# How am I able to select items when using VoiceOver for supporting blind people?

Tags: iphone, ios, select, accessibility, voiceover

I'm using VoiceOver in one of my Apps and want to make it more accessible to blind people.

When loading up a viewcontroller a scrollview is displayed with multiple textviews in there. I would like to automaticly select the first textview when opening up my viewcontroller. Is there a workaround for these needs?

I'm using a navigationcontroller and a tabbarcontroller. At the moment the voiceover selects the backbutton firstly but I would like to select another UI part.

Comment: did you get a solution for UILabel s ? The accepted answer works well for a text view but not for a UILabel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution to automatically begin editing the first UITextView is to put this in the ViewDidLoad method:

```
[textView becomeFirstResponder];
```

Make sure you've setup your UITextView protocols and delegates and this should work.